# 3 HTML5 Videos in Modals, but only 1 stops and restarts upon closing

Tags: javascript, html, video, modal-dialog

Below is my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that I used to create the modal. The onclick event only works for one modal and not the other two. I need the video to stop and restart once the modal is closed. This should happen for each modal when they are closed. The stop and restart of the video either works for the first video or the last, but I need it to work for all 3 videos.

HTML

```
<!----Video Modals--->
<input class="modal-state" id="emailModal" type="checkbox" />
<div class="modal">
  <label onclick="stop_and_restart()"  class="modal__bg" for="emailModal" ></label>
  <div class="modal__inner">
    <label onclick="stop_and_restart()" class="modal__close" for="emailModal"></label>
    <h2></h2>
    <p style="text-align:center"><video id="video" width="624px" height="352px" controls >
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video. 
</video></p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--- Video - 2--->
<input class="modal-state" id="dashboardModal" type="checkbox" />
<div class="modal">
  <label onclick="stop_and_restart()"  class="modal__bg" for="dashboardModal"  ></label>
  <div class="modal__inner">
    <label onclick="stop_and_restart()"  class="modal__close" for="dashboardModal"></label>
    <h2></h2>
    <p style="text-align:center"><video id="video" width="624px" height="352px" controls >
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video. 
</video></p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--- Video - 3 --->
<input class="modal-state" id="calendarModal" type="checkbox" />
<div class="modal">
  <label onclick="stop_video1()" class="modal__bg" for="calendarModal" ></label>
  <div class="modal__inner">
    <label onclick="stop_video1()" class="modal__close" for="calendarModal"></label>
    <h2></h2>
    <p style="text-align:center"><video id="video" width="624px" height="352px" controls >
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video. 
</video></p>
  </div>
</div>
<!---Video Modals - End --->
```

CSS -

```
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: table;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .modal-container {
    width: 100%;
    }
}


.modal-header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #42b983;
}

.modal-body {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.modal-default-button {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 24px; 
      margin: 10px;
        float:right;
      color: #aaa;
}



.modal-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-enter .modal-container,
.modal-leave-active .modal-container {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

JavaScript -

```
 var vid = document.getElementById("video");
   function stop_and_restart() {
    vid.pause();
    vid.currentTime=0;
    }
```

Comment: What else did you try? If so, update your question by posting it. It shows effort.

Comment: this doesn't show enough to reproduce the issue - what is the name of the element in each model for instance?